# Setar um atributo de outra classe

Tags: java, jsf

Estou construindo uma lista em JSF, que utiliza atributos de duas classes (`ItemdoPedido` e `Produto`).

Meu `ManagedBean` se baseia na classe `ItemdoPedido`, então a dificuldade está em setar e recuperar o valor da classe `Produto`.

Classes do modelo:

```
public class Produto{

    public int id;
    public String descricao;
    /* getters and setters */
}

public class ItemDoPedido{

    private int id;
    private int quantidade;
    private Produto p;
}
```

Esse é o meu DAO que constrói a lista e é chamado no bean:

```
public class ItemdoPedidoDAO {    
      public List<ItemDoPedido> MostrarPedidos() {

            Connection con = Conexao.getConnection();

            PreparedStatement stmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;

            List<ItemDoPedido> itens = new ArrayList<>();

            try {
                stmt = con.prepareStatement("select p.id as id_pedido, i.qtdade as qtdade, r.descricao as descricao\n"
                        + "from cliente c inner join pedido p on c.id = p.id_cliente\n"
                        + " join item_do_pedido i on p.id = i.id_pedido\n"
                        + " join produto r on i.id_produto = r.id\n"
                        + " where c.cpf = '982139812'"
                        + "");
                rs = stmt.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next()) {

                    ItemDoPedido i = new ItemDoPedido();
                    Produto produto = new Produto();

                    i.setId(rs.getInt("id_pedido"));
                    i.setQuantidade(rs.getInt("qtdade"));
                    i.setP(produto.setDescricao(rs.getString("descricao")));
                    itens.add(i);
               }        
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ClienteDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {
                Conexao.closeConnection(con, stmt, rs);
            }
            return itens;
        }
    }
```

O problema está na classe acima, na linha:

```
i.setP(produto.setDescricao(rs.getString("descricao")));
```

Ela dá o seguinte erro:

> VOID TYPE NOT ALLOWED HERE

Esse é meu bean, getters and setter não aparecem mas estão incluídos:

```
@ManagedBean(name="pedidoMB")
@SessionScoped
public class pedidoMB {

    private ItemDoPedido item;
    private Produto produto;
    private List<ItemDoPedido> itens;
    private ItemdoPedidoDAO iDAO = new ItemdoPedidoDAO();


    public pedidoMB() {
        item = new ItemDoPedido();
        produto = new Produto();
        itens = iDAO.MostrarPedidos(); 
    }
```

Essa é a parte da minha tela que mostra os dados:

```
<h:form> 
            <p:panel header="Pedidos">
                <p:link outcome="index" value="Voltar"></p:link>
                <p:dataTable var="item" value="#{pedidoMB.itens}">
                <p:column  headerText="Id">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.id}" />
                </p:column>

                 <p:column  headerText="Quantidade">
                     <h:outputText value="#{item.quantidade}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column  headerText="Produto">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.p.descricao}" />
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
```

Ao final, a minha ideia é exbir algo assim:

```
ID | QUANTIDADE | PRODUTO
1  |    10      | CADERNO
2  |    20      | CANETA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se os *getters* e *setters* foram implementados da maneira "tradicional", imagino que estejam assim:

```
public class Produto{
    ... // demais campos, setters, getters, etc
    public String descricao;

    public void setDescricao(String desc) {
        this.descricao = desc;
    }
}

public class ItemDoPedido{
    ... // demais campos, setters, getters, etc
    private Produto p;

    public void setP(Produto p) {
        this.p = p;
    }
}
```

*Sem entrar no mérito de ter um método chamado `setP`, que é um nome bem ruim (não seria melhor ser `setProduto`?), mas enfim...*

Repare que `setDescricao` é um método `void`, ou seja, ele não retorna nenhum valor. E ao fazer:

```
i.setP(produto.setDescricao(rs.getString("descricao")));
```

Você está chamando `setP` (que espera um `Produto` como parâmetro), mas em vez disso está passando o retorno do método `setDescricao`. Só que `setDescricao` não retorna nada, pois é um método `void`, daí o erro de *"void type not allowed here"*.

Para funcionar, basta separar as chamadas e passar o parâmetro correto para `setP`:

```
produto.setDescricao(rs.getString("descricao"));
i.setP(produto);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, com a tua explicação eu realmente entendi, testei e deu certo.